# understanding output of "order" function in R

Tags: r, ranking

Given this data frame:

```
names <- c("Anna", "Bella", "Christian", "Derrick", "Emma")
scores <- c(10,5,10,9,8)
age <- c(16,16,17,18,21)
test <- data.frame(cbind(names,scores, age))
```

I wish to create a variable that ranks by **scores** and uses **names** as a tie-breaker 
i.e. though Anna and Christian both score 10, Anna's rank == 1 & Christian's == 2

my code: `test$rank_by_score <- order(test$scores, test$names, decreasing = T)`

current output:

```
names      scores   age   rank_by_score
Anna       10       16    4
Bella      5        16    5
Christian  10       17    2
Derrick    9        18    3
Emma       8        21    1
```

desired output:

```
names      scores   age   rank_by_score
Anna       10       16    1
Bella      5        16    5
Christian  10       17    2
Derrick    9        18    3
Emma       8        21    4
```

What's happening in my current output and how do I get to my desired output ?

**editing to show output when *age* and *scores* are coded as integers rather than factors**

```
names      scores   age   rank_by_score
Anna       10       16    3
Bella      5        16    1
Christian  10       17    4
Derrick    9        18    5
Emma       8        21    2
```

Comment: Note that `cbind(names,scores, age)` coerces everything to character, then `data.frame(.)` defaults to `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. And the scores are now coded as consecutive integers from the smallest, `10`, **not** `5` **!** The proper way to crate a df from vectors is to not use `cbind`. Remove it and your results are completely different.

Comment: noticed after posting but even after adjusting for it (using `cbind.data.frame` & `as.int`) ranking wasn't sound

Comment: Yes, I know that the rankings were still wrong. What I was trying to say is that you don't need `cbind`, not even `cbind.data.frame`. The way to do it is `data.frame(names,scores, age)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `rank` rather than `order` but `rank` can take only one column value. So we can first `order` the data based on `names` and then use `rank`.

```
test <- test[order(test$names), ]

rank(-test$scores, ties.method = "first")
#[1] 1 5 2 3 4
```

See `?rank` for different `ties.method` options. If we use `ties.method = "first"` when there is a tie small number is given to the entry which occurs first and opposite when `ties.method = "last"`.

```
rank(-test$scores, ties.method = "last")
#[1] 2 5 1 3 4
```

---

`order` returns indices of the original vector in sorted order.

```
a1 <- order(test$scores, decreasing = TRUE)
a1
#[1] 1 3 4 5 2

a2 <- test$scores
a2
#[1] 10  5 10  9  8
```

Here, the output of `order` can be interpreted as `a2[a1[1]]` (10) is the biggest number followed by `a2[a1[2]]` (10) and `a2[a1[3]]` (9) and so on.

**data**

```
names <- c("Anna", "Bella", "Christian", "Derrick", "Emma")
scores <- c(10,5,10,9,8)
age <- c(16,16,17,18,21)
test <- data.frame(names, scores, age)
```